# How to get retrieve twitter user id from twitter handle using the twitter v2 API

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, twitter

I am currently using the twitter v2 API, using the following npm package [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-api-v2)

```
const tweets = await client.v2.userTimeline(userId, { exclude: 'replies' });
```

I require the userID and not the twitter handle for this command.

How would I be able to get the twitter user id from the twitter handle using the twitter API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `client.v2.userByUsername('handle');` and get the ID value from the response.